# non-generic type extending a generic type without specifying type parameter(s)

Tags: java, generics

Is it a valid design to extend an generic class without specifying a type parameter. I don't really care about the type parameter and want to discontinue the generics under my class's hierarchy.

E.g.,: if there is a class `A<T,U>` where `T` and `U` are type parameters.

```
class B extends A { ... }
```

Also, is it possible to specify one parameter and skip the other? What will be the syntax? Following did not work:

```
class C<U> extends A<?,U> { ... }
```

Comment: Relevant:  [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis in my case the hierarchy has become very complex and I don't have enough time to remove the type parameters from top down. Hence trying to reduce its use in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Not specifying a type is called a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). The problem with it is that it lets you do unsafe stuff.

Here is a quick example:

```
class A<T> {
    T t;
}

class B extends A {
}

// somewhere
A<String> a = new B();
```

A warning is raised for the assignment but it is perfectly compilable Java.

> Also, is it possible to specify one parameter and skip the other?

No, not really. For your situation I would recommend parameterizing with Object. (If the parameter is declared with an upper bound like `<T extends SomeType>` use SomeType instead of Object.)

```
class B extends A<Object, Object> { ... }
class C<U> extends A<Object, U> { ... }
```

That will behave normally and won't let you do anything insane by accident.

Comment: I should have included this code in the question. But in my case, I am inheriting an interface from this interface: `SuperInterface<T extends SuperInterface<T, K>, K extends ParentInterface> extends SuperSuperInterface<T>`  How can I extend my interface from `SuperInterface` above?

Comment: @AsadIqbal That looks like a recursive generic. My best guess is like `class Sub extends SuperInterface<Sub, ParentInterface>`. But I don't know anything about how your project's classes are used.